# python string and variable

Tags: python, string, variables

Is there any other method in Python that can change a string to a variable? 
For example, I have some variables named button1, button2, button3, etc. I want to operate on them in a loop. If I don't want to use eval, anything else suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `globals` and `locals` which return a dictionary mapping of your current namespace.

e.g.:

```
a = 1
print globals()['a']  #1
```

`globals` should be used if the variable is defined at the module level, `locals` should be used for everything else.  In your case, I would think that `locals()['button1']` would do the trick.

---

Having said that, it's probably a better idea to just put the buttons in a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. I think putting them in a dictionary is a good solution.

Comment: I'm very happy to improve this answer if you leave a comment about what might be wrong with it :)

Comment: Sorry to come so late. Thank you again. I've already solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you asked, but what is wrong with:

```
  for btn in (button1, button2, button3):
      do_something(btn)
```

Answer (score -1):

The [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) and [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) function return dictionaries that you can use to manipulate global and local variables directly:

```
# sets the global variable foo (in the scope of the module) to 1
# equivalent to
#   foo = 1
# outside a functions
globals()['foo'] = 1

# gets the local variable bar (in the scope of the current function)
# equivalent to
#   print bar
# inside a function
print locals()['bar']
```

When you're using `locals()` outside of a function, it would be equivalent to using `globals()`.

If you want to manipulate the properties of an object, you can use [`getattr(obj, name)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr(obj, name, value)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) instead:

```
# equivalent to
#   print foo.x
print getattr(foo, 'x')

# equivalent to
#   foo.x = 45
setattr(foo, 'x', 45)
```

---

**EDIT**: As [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) pointed out, using `locals()` cannot reliably be used for setting variable values within a function. It would also be much smarter to just contain all the buttons in a separate dictionary anyways.

Comment: You can't rely on modifying `locals()` this way, as [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) warn.  Try changing `bar` in a function and sticking `print bar` before and after the `locals()['bar']` assignment.